# Excel button with click macro to call new spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet where each tab is for a different client. I have 5 buttons in each tab corresponding to 5 different spreadsheets. Can I make my macro code generic, where depending on which client I am in (the tab of a specific client), the code represents that client. Right now, I have code specific for each button:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "\\some\folder\johndoe\Estimate\johndoe_Estimate.xls" _
```

I would like the code where it calls the name johndoe to be able to call the name of the tab that I am in.

I already can fill in cells based on the tab name. Now, I need to fill in *code* based on the tab that is active.

Answer (score 0):

"ActiveSheet.Name" however if you are inside the code of the spreadsheet you can use "Me.Name" which is useful if the sheet is not actually active but the code is getting run.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "\\some\folder\johndoe\Estimate\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".xls"
```